# Mount a new partition to existing mount point

Tags: linux, mount, partition

Similar question has already been asked on SF but I have a slight difference that might create issues if I follow already answered question's solution, therefore I must make sure.

I have a 4TB HDD mounted as /var. The space on this HDD is almost up, which is why I added another 4TB HDD that is not mounted yet. What I plan to do is create a mount point for this new HDD `/mnt/a/` for example and then use `mhddfs` utility to merge `/var` and `/mnt/a`  into a single mount point of `/var` with possibly following command:

```
mhddfs /var/,/mnt/a/ /var/
```

So that the two HDDs both have a single mount point of `/var` and no restart of the server to be necessary. 
Does `mhddfs` support executing such command when the resulting mount point is the same as one of the *to-be-merged* mount points? Or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:
The idea is for the /var/www/html/  directory to show files that are present in /mnt/a/www/html/ as well as the files that currently reside in /var/www/html/

Answer (score 0):

If you used LVM, adding the disk as a physical volume and extending the logical volume can all be done online. (Both disks would be required to bring the volumes online.)

Or, mounting over can also be done online.

1. Mount existing /var a 2nd time at /mnt/var
2. Mount new www at /mnt/www
3. Copy files from /mnt/var  to /mnt/www
4. Edit /etc/fstab to mount new www at /var/www and mount it
5. Clean up old files from /mnt/var  at your convenience

Note that it is possible to mount a volume at at any point in the tree, such as /var/www.

This may not gain you much if /var/www consumes most of the space of /var. Consider bigger disks (arrays).